# How does Load Balancing work in Kubernetes EKS with ELB and Kube-Proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, load-balancing, docker-network, kube-proxy

[image]

Given the above diagram. How does Load Balancing work in Kubernetes EKS? To my understanding it works like that:

1. Elastic Load Balancer balances the call between worker nodes (in my case it redirect the call to the Node 1 as shown with the purple arrow)
2. Then the kube-proxy on the node which was picked by the Load Balancer (Node 1) checks the Ip Tables to route the traffic the correct pod according to a Round Robin mechanism, the pod choosed by the Round Robin can be located also inside another node (since they are all connected to the same overlay network)

QUESTIONS:

1. Is the flow described above correct?
2. Is it corrected to say that ELB balances at Node level and Kube-Proxy at Cluster Level?
3. Which caller ip address sees the final pod? The client ip address? the ELB ip address? or the Node Ip Address where it lies the Kube-Proxy replica that balanced the traffic (so in my case the Node 1 Ip Address)?